# Difference between view and template in Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

In a Grails app, I am trying to figure out when to use a view and when to use a template for a gsp.  Are there any obvious reasons?  Or does it just come down to reuse?

Comment: `Re-usability` and `sharing` are the major advantages of templates, you can modularize your pages with smaller templates or render a common template across all your pages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically Template is a (reusable) part of a View. Useful for splitting View into logical parts and/or for reusing same code from different views.

So, if you're rendering a whole page - use View. If you need just a small part - use Template.

See docs for Views and Templates - http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#viewsAndTemplates