# Grails formRemote 404 Not Found

Tags: grails

I'm having difficulties getting my ajaxform working properly. I'm using Grails 2.4.4 and have the following remoteForm code.

**view usedProducts**

```
<div id="updateMe">
    <g:each in="${productList}" var="product">
        ${product.item} Success1
    </g:each>
</div>

<g:formRemote name="myForm"
    url="[controller:'product', action: 'save']" update="updateMe">
    <g:textField name="item" required="" value="${newProduct?.item}" />
    <g:submitButton name="Save" />
</g:formRemote>
```

**Controller ProductController**

```
def usedProducts = {
    [productList:Product.findAll()]
}

@Transactional
def save(Product productInstance) {
    productInstance.save flush:true

    [productList: Product.findAll()]
}
```

**Console Error**

POST http://localhost:8080/TekDays/product/save

404 Not Found
        54ms
jquery-...e=false (line 9631)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/TekDays/product/save"

Comment: Do you have a file called save.gsp? Note that the method save (controller) returns the model to a gsp that need to have the same name: save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot do that this way you're trying to do.

Note that when the AJAX call is effectively being performed by the user there are no more GSP tags. There are only CSS, HTML and Javascript. It's the browser world.

Please put the render in front of what you're returning and test.

```
@Transactional
def save(Product productInstance) {
    productInstance.save flush:true    
    render Product.findAll()   
}
```

You'll see that the content of the DIV updateMe will be replaced by the content rendered by the save method. The content is a list returned by findAll method with all Product objects.

When you use render the content returned (a GSP template, the content of a variable or a HTML) will be rendered in the current HTML, for instance, through an AJAX call.

For other side when you use the return keyword is expected a GSP with the same name as the controller method. Because of that you're getting a 404, since a save.gsp isn't found. Note: if you omit the return keyword (as you're doing) then the groovyc (Groovy compiler) will implicitly put it for you.

If I understand well what you're trying to do then you must render the content (not return it).

Comment: So i looks as if render resolved that issue, the only issue I'm having now is my object in the list is only display the domain package. example [com.tekdays.Product : 1, com.tekdays.Product : 2, com.tekdays.Product : 3, com.tekdays.Product : 4] Any thoughts?

Comment: @CodeJunkie you're rendering the return of .toString() of Grails Domain Object which is the class name followed by the database ID of object (com.tekdays.Product : 1). If you want to render a property of your class try to do the following: Product.findAll().property (replace .property with some attribute of your domain class).

Comment: I'm very new to Grails coming from Tapestry. Tapestry had the concept where you would surround your list in the template with a zone and when that zone would refresh, it would refresh your template list with a new object from the backend. If I understand things correctly with grails, this is not the case, grails can't pass in your object data into the each, you would manually be required to do as you just said or create a template? Again, very new to grails.

Comment: @CodeJunkie, you can render a value directly. Example: render Product.findAll(). You can render an HTML snippet directly. Example: render "<b>${Product.findAll()}</b>". Finally, you can render a GSP template. Example: render(template:"bookTemplate", model:[book:b]), where bookTemplate is a GSP that must to start with the underscore character: _bookTemplate.gsp. Templates are a very flexible way to reuse code and its use is highly recommended because of that (See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272250/difference-between-view-and-template-in-grails).

Comment: @CodeJunkie, I forgot to say that you can render a GSP template from another GSP, example: <g:render template="updateTemplate"/>. I highly recommend you to read more about GSP templates since is a powerful functionality of the Grails framework.

Comment: Thanks Cantoni, I'm not actually building an application just yet, just ring to learn everything I can about the framework before moving on to a real app. the GSP's are a little different than what I'm use too.

Comment: One more question, why can my each statement above work perfectly displaying the object values on page load with this code respond Product.findAll() but the render only returns a String? Thanks, I'll do more reading on GSP's too

Comment: @CodeJunkie, this happens because GSP taglibs as <g:each> doesn't exists in the web browser. They exists only in the server. After a GSP is rendered the ouput contains only HTML, CSS and Javascript. Did you get it?

Comment: Yes I get it, I just wish that piece was closer to the tapestry design. It seems a little bit more cumbersome to deal with in grails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79771/discussion-between-cantoni-and-code-junkie).